# `htop` for disk I/O?

Tags: ssh, files, process, disk

I´m searching for an `ssh` tool that displays what process is reading/writing on which file.

Example output:

> pid (or like htop command) | read mb/s | write mb/s | path/to/file.txt

Comment: Maybe `iotop` is [almost] what you are looking for. Install it and run for example `sudo iotop -o`

Comment: almost yes .. but there i don´t the the path of files and i can not sort it .. its hard to follow that specific task i´m looking for

Comment: See also: [Command line tool on Ubuntu Server to see disk IO stats?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/460/command-line-tool-on-ubuntu-server-to-see-disk-io-stats)

Answer (score 10):

`iotop` is what I'd recommend first. You can use the `-o` flag to be more precise. Keep in mind that if you're using CentOS and one of the latest kernel versions, you'll have to edit the below section of `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/data.py`:

```
def parse_proc_pid_status(pid):
    result_dict = {}
    try:
        for line in open('/proc/%d/status' % pid):
            if not line.strip(): continue
            key, value = line.split(':\t', 1)
            result_dict[key] = value.strip()
    except IOError:
        pass  # No such process
```

Add the line that says: `if not line.strip(): continue`.

You can also use `fuser` to show the processes accessing a file with:

```
fuser -v -m <file>
```

It just won't show whether or not the process is writing to it.

You can also use `lsof` on the file itself or by piping in to grep for the filename or process.

```
lsof /path/to/file
lsof | grep <filename>
lsof | grep <process>
```

To get exactly what you want, you're going to have to use a combination unless you already know the file that's being written to and you just want to see the process that's writing to it.

Comment: i´m on debian :) but i´ts not excatly what i´m looking for as i answered above :) i know it from windows "resource monitor" there i can see exactly what prozess is writing/reading on what files.

Comment: @wuast94 See my edit above. You're going to have to use a combination of things to get what you want.